# Why does "Vue init" hang?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have installed npm 6.9.0 and Node.js 10.16.0. I have installed vue-cli. Now when I run

`vue init webpack <some_name>`

The wizard asks me to enter the project name, and then the description. I hit "Enter" for the project name. I try to hit "Enter" for the project description as well, but I cannot. Even Ctrl+C doesn't work. The process just hangs.

I have tried completely reinstalling vue and npm. Did not help.

Comment: Which version of vue-cli are you using?

Comment: @AlexMulchinock, 2.9.6

Comment: Have you not found any information relating to issues with your version of the CLI? Google turned up quite a few Github issues describing your problem. One solution seems to be upgrading to vue-cli version 3...

Comment: What operating system, and what command line program?

Comment: @AlexMulchinock, I have found some answers but they were only about upgrading npm. I will try to update vue.

Comment: @Ferrybig, MacOS Mojave 10.14.3. Classic Terminal.

Comment: @AlexMulchinock, I have upgraded vue to 3.8.4. This did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the temporary fix of vue init command.

**PowerShell (Windows):**

```
cd "$(Split-Path $(whereis vue)[0] -Parent)\node_modules\@vue\cli-init"
npm i inquirer@~6.3.1
```

**bash:**

```
cd "$(dirname $(which vue))/node_modules/@vue/cli-init"
npm i inquirer@~6.3.1
```

Downgrading node doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Node to 8.0.0 solves the issue

Comment: I have tried both approaches. None worked.

1. Have done `npm init -y`. Edited the description and project name in package.json. 

2. Edited `~/.vuerc` file.

3. Deleted `~/.vuerc` file

After each try I have tried to run `vue init` once again - but got the same result as before